# Javascript object/function accesibility inside another one

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I was looking for best solution, but I dont really what keyword should I look for. I need a bit of explanation of my problem :) Thats my code:

```
function fluidEdge(params) {
  var fluid = {};
  fluid.point = function(config){
    fluid.x = config.x;
    fluid.y = config.y; 
  };
  fluid.renderShape = function(params){
    params = params || {};
        var x = params.x || 0;
        var y = params.y || 0;
    point = new fluid.point({
      x: x,
      y: y
    });
    console.log(point.x);
  };

  return fluid;
}

var test = new fluidEdge({});

test.renderShape({x: 50, y: 100});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8fp5ugq4/)

My example is much more complicated, so I can't really rebuild code, I've simplified it as much as I could. I want to access `fluid.point` function inside `fluid.renderShape`. I have no idea how I could do it, I tried few ways.

Before I wasn't using `var fluid = {};` and `fluid.` everywhere but `this.` and everything was working well.

If I am making any mistakes, you can point that out too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code is quite confusing .  What is `var fluid = {};` for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a slight mixup with how constructors and functions work. Your code should probably look somewhat like this:

```
function FluidEdge(params) {}

FluidEdge.Point = function(config) {
  this.x = config.x;
  this.y = config.y;
}

FluidEdge.prototype.renderShape = function(params) {
  params = params || {};
  var x = params.x || 0;
  var y = params.y || 0;

  var point = new FluidEdge.Point({x: x, y: y});

  console.log(point.x);
}

var test = new FluidEdge({});
test.renderShape({x: 50, y: 100});
```

Note the use of `prototype` to denote methods on the constructor, and the use of `this` to refer to the constructed object.

Also note that placing constructors on instance variables is generally a bad idea, unless you know what you're doing and have a very good reason to.

Worth noting that this code becomes *much* better looking if you take advantage of ES2015 features

```
class FluideEdge {
  renderShape({x = 0, y = 0}) {
    var point = new FluidEdge.Point({x, y});
    console.log(point.x);
  }
}
FluidEdge.Point = class {
  constructor({x, y}) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}
```

Comment: It works, but still I think nested code is more clean. Using prototype everytime after first function declaration seems a bit ugly. I took my ideas from http://checkman.io/blog/creating-a-javascript-library/ . I like the ES2015 way tbh :)

Comment: That's fine, but they aren't using constructors (the `new` keyword). You shouldn't get your terms mixed up ;)

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that I just changed too many `this` into `fluid` in my code. The problem was there:

```
fluid.point = function(config){
  this.x = config.x;
  this.y = config.y; 
};
```

It works well after that small change.